# Unable to get site title using JSOM

Tags: javascript, jsom, sp.js

I am trying to get a site title property using JSOM, but i get can't read prperty 'title' of undefined. Can someone help me understand this error message?

```
function getRootWeb() {
    //Get and load a reference to the root web of the current site collection.
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("http://Server/sites/sitecollection/");
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();

    ctx.load(rootWeb);
    //Ask SharePoint to pull data for us
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceed,onQueryFailed);
};

//Function executed on success
 function onQuerySucceed() {
    alert(this.rootWeb.get_title());
};

//Function executed on failure
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Unable to retrieve data from the SharePoint. Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rootWeb is out of scope in your OnQuerySucceed function.  When you first define it using `var`, it is in the scope of your getRootWeb function.  When you call `this.rootWeb` it is looking for a rootWeb variable with global scope.  Change the line where you first define rootWeb to use `this`:

this.rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `this`.

Also, you can write it inside the anon function instead of a specific success or failure function:

```
function getRootWeb() {
    //Get and load a reference to the root web of the current site collection.
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("http://Server/sites/sitecollection/");
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();

    ctx.load(rootWeb);
    //Ask SharePoint to pull data for us
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        // success function
        alert(rootWeb.get_title());
    },function(sender, args){
        // failure function
        alert('Unable to retrieve data from the SharePoint. Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
};
```